# get previous next row using PDO to create links

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i've got some bad sytax in my query where i'm trying to create 'prev_id' to pull into the $row result link. any ideas on a better way of doing this?

edit: the error is "Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'prev_id'."

```
function traversePhoto($the_selected_id) {
global $pdo;

$id = $the_selected_id;

$stmt_a = $pdo->prepare("
    (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id < '.intval($id).' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
     UNION (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM images)) LIMIT 1 prev_id");
$stmt_b = $pdo->prepare("
    (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id > '.intval($id).' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
     UNION (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM images)) LIMIT 1 next_id");

// $vars = array(':id' => $id);
$prev = $stmt_a->execute();
$next = $stmt_b->execute();

if ($prev) {
    while($row = $stmt_a->fetchObject()) {
        echo '<a href="' . $row['prev_id'] . '">Previous</a>';
    } 
} else {
    echo 'no previous';
}

if ($next) {
    while($row = $stmt_b->fetchObject()) {
        echo '<a href="' . $row['next_id'] . '">Next</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'no next';
}
```

}

Comment: you can try storing the query result in sessions and work with that tracking where is current position of user,etc .. instead of recalculate what's previous,next,last etc, on every page request

Comment: geo - what would that look like?

Comment: Please don't use `global`s...

Comment: @jessicaldale: Yes, don't use `global`. They are *evil* and break encapsulation: [Exhibit A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/420001) | [Exhibit B](http://my.opera.com/zomg/blog/2007/08/30/globals-are-evil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<?php function traversePhoto($the_selected_id) {
global $pdo;

$id = $the_selected_id;

$stmt_a = $pdo->prepare("
(SELECT * FROM images WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
 UNION (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM images)) LIMIT 1");
$stmt_b = $pdo->prepare("
(SELECT * FROM images WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
 UNION (SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM images)) LIMIT 1");

// $vars = array(':id' => $id);
$prev = $stmt_a->execute(array( (int)$id ));
$next = $stmt_b->execute(array( (int)$id ));

if ($stmt_a->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt_a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<a href="' . $row['prev_id'] . '">Previous</a>';
    } 
 } else {
    echo 'no previous';
}

if ($stmt_b->rowCount() > 0) {
   while($row = $stmt_b->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      echo '<a href="' . $row['next_id'] . '">Next</a>';
  }
} else {
echo 'no next';
}
```

Comment: it is fetch_assoc. It is better to use this this way, but I got lazy: `$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: thanks John - it still does not like my use of 'prev_id' and 'next_id' in my query.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be `$stmt_a->rowCount()`, not $prev->rowCount(). I edited my post.

Comment: I cannot see what your tables look like. But I think you should replace  `$row['next_id']` and `$row['prev_id']` by `$row['id']`

Comment: i was trying to create 'next_id' (as an Alias??) from the sql query to be used to create the link href. does that make sense?

Comment: No, that make no sense that way, sorry I did not see that last piece of your sql code. You can use `SELECT id as next_id FROM` if you like it that way.

And you should enable errors so you can see what is going on.

Comment: ah, makes sense. so i can wrap a  SELECT  id as next_id around each query.

Comment: I don't know what you ment by wrap. But here is the complete query: `(SELECT `id` as `next_id` FROM images WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)`.